# How to have a function act on non-argument variables?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am trying to write a function which will take in multiple indices and do something based on the values in an array at those indices. If I do not declare the arrays as arguments to the function (which will always operate on the same two arrays) I get X/Y was not declared in this scope, but if I do attempt to declare them, I get "error: declaration of ‘X’ as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first," and the bounds are not known until runtime.

Is there any way to do this in a function, or do I have to explicitly write the code in main every time?

Code:

```
double foo(int A, int B, int t){//A, B, and t are indices 
  int x = X[A][t]-X[B][t]; //X and Y are 2D arrays
  int y = Y[A][t]-Y[B][t];
  double d;
  //do some math ...
  return d;
}

int main{
.
.
.
int X[nPeople][tMax]={0};
int Y[nPeople][tMax]={0};
.
.
.
for(int t=0; t<tMax; t++){
  for(int n=0; n<nPeople; n++){
    foo(n,a,t);
  }
}
.
.
.
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: allocate `X` and `Y` dinamically

Comment: Use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`

Comment: If you don't pass arrays as arguments, they should be global...

Comment: Those are C-style arrays. The whole snippet actually is C code, not C++, otherwise `foo` would be a method of a class where `X` and `Y` are private members, also resolving name scopes quite nicely. But for declaration without knowing the size at compile time: yes, either make them `int *` and allocate dynamically or make them `vector` instances for more safety.

Comment: While it is easy to fix by declaring global `X` and `Y`before their uses, it is not a good practice as at some point, you might want to have more than one instance of the data. For C code, putting data in a `struct` and passing a pointer would be the way. For C++, better solutions are already explained by others.

Comment: Re: 'int X[nPeople][tMax]={0};" -- if the array sizes are not known at compile time, this code is not valid C++. Some compilers provide such a monstrosity as an extension. As others have said, use `std::vector`. This is what it was designed for.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways:

1- Use built-in std::vector library with the following inclusion:

```
#include <vector>
```

Vectors are dynamic arrays so when you initialize them they do not have a strict capacity which you can never change. On constrast, they grow larger with each element you push or insert. As far as I can see you are dealing with matrices so you need two dimensional arrays, no problem. Here is the code for it:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> >
```

2- Use global variables. Variables that are declared outside of the functions are considered global so they will be visible to every function beneath it. Altough it is not considered to be good coding practise because of the bugs it may cause in a large scale problem, if you are confident enough that it will not pose a threat to your code safety/cleanness, go ahead use it!

3- Use dynamically allocated arrays and pass the pointers as parameters so that you can deal with any size you want

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways a function can work with data:

- Use global data:

  ```
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> X;
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> Y;

  double foo(int A, int B, int t){ //A, B, and t are indices 
    int x = X[A][t]-X[B][t]; // X and Y are global 2D arrays
    int y = Y[A][t]-Y[B][t];
    double d;
    //do some math ...
    return d;
  }
  ```

  unfortunately shown too many times in sample code, but (mutable) global have lot of issues (hard to test, hard to re-use the code, hard to reason about the code)
- Pass them as arguments:

  ```
  double foo(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& X, // X and Y are 2D arrays

             const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& Y, // As we can see, so unneeded comment
             int A, int B, int t){ //A, B, and t are indices 
    int x = X[A][t]-X[B][t];
    int y = Y[A][t]-Y[B][t];
    double d;
    //do some math ...
    return d;
  }
  ```
- bind them using a class:

  ```
  class C
  {
      std::vector<std::vector<int>> X;
      std::vector<std::vector<int>> Y;
   public:
      double foo(int A, int B, int t){ //A, B, and t are indices 
        int x = X[A][t]-X[B][t]; // X and Y are member 2D arrays (it should be trivial (`this->` might help), so comment not needed neither)
        int y = Y[A][t]-Y[B][t];
        double d;
        //do some math ...
        return d;
      }
  };
  ```

  care to create coherent classes and avoid [god class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) (which have mostly same default as global).